# Countability and convergence in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, pointwise-convergence, nets

The main Idea here is that sequence convergence in not first countable spaces is not enough to explain closure and continuity. I want to discuss this with two examples:

(1) Lets have $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the Topology of pintwise convergence and lets have the subset

$ E:=\{g\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)\neq 0 \textit{ only for finite many } x\}$

Lets have than the constant function $f(x)=1$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Now it is $f\in cl(E)$ but there is no sequence that has $f$ as limit because of the definition of $g$.

(2) Lets $\Omega=[0,\omega_1]$ and $\Omega_0=[0,\omega_1)$. Here we have $\omega_1\in cl(\Omega_0)$ but aswell no sequence in $\Omega_0$ convergent to $\omega_1$.

Based on this there should be

(1) A net in $E$ convergent to $1$.

(2) A net in  $\Omega_0$ convergent to $\omega_1$

How can I approach such problems? Is there a way to find such a net for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for any space, including these: Let $x \in \overline{E}$ and let the directe set for the net be $\mathcal{O}_x$, the set of open neighbourhoods of $x$, directed by $O \le O' \iff O' \subseteq O$ (smaller neighbourhoods as sets are bigger, the intersection of two neighbourhoods is a common upper bound).

For each $O \in \mathcal{O}_x$ pick $f(O) \in O \cap E$. This $f: \mathcal{O}_x \to X$ is is a net in $E$ that converges to $x$. This is clear from the definitions.

For $(2)$ we can also use $\Omega_0$ as the directed set and the identity as the net. Nice and efficient, and no choice required.

For $(1)$ and alternative net is : the finite subsets of $\Bbb R$ as directed set $F$ with inclusion as direction, and $x_F$ the point that is $1$ on $F$ and $0$ outside of $F$. Some thought will reveal that this converges to the constant $1$ function.

Both are really the standard (first one) in disguise, but made more explicit.